# Sequelize: Is it possible to return custom field names instead of regular field names?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

For example I have this model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    user_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
  });

    return Users;
};
```

Currently when I make a get call for info, I get `user_name` as the name of the field. I'm wondering if its possible to return `username` without the underscore instead of the actual field name. In other words, an alias. I'm just using this as an example, but overall would like to know how it can be done to any field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just as an ORM user, I would think you would do this when you do your SELECT statements, as in `SELECT *, user_name AS username`, not in your model definition. Obviously in your case using Sequelize syntax but I hope that it makes the point.

Comment: I definitely get what you're getting at. I understand in the case of a few fields I could set an alias specifically in the call. `Users.findAll({ attributes:[['user_name','username']] //'user_name AS username}).then(function(posts) { res.json(posts); });` I guess I'm just curious if it can be set in the model so if I make other calls or have lots of fields I could save time.

Answer (score 0):

```
username: {
  type: new DataTypes.VIRTUAL(DataTypes.STRING, ['user_name']),
  get: function () {
    return this.get('user_name');
 }
}
```

Comment: I now see my set function isn't being called, tried debugging with console.log string with your example and it never hits. Is there something I need to in the model for set() to be called?

Comment: Would I build fields in the model this way instead of the way I did above? I thought the fields had to be the exact same as you have it in the database table I'm using for CRUD

Comment: just add this under ur user_name field. this doesn't build anything in the database, just a virtual getter field which is made up from `user_name` .

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me

```
username: { 
  type: DataTypes.STRING, 
  field: 'user_name', 
  allowNull: false 
}
```

Now outputs `username` instead of actual field name `user_name`